# Flow error - property 'contains' not found in EventTarget

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

Please help me to workaround with this **error**:

```
if (!evt.currentTarget.contains(evt.relatedTarget)) {
                       ^^^^^^^^ property `contains`. Property not found in
if (!evt.currentTarget.contains(evt.relatedTarget)) {
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ EventTarget
```

Here's a part of related **Navigation.jsx** component's code :

```
 class Navigation extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    open: false
  };
  ...
  handleClickOutside = (evt: SyntheticMouseEvent<> &
                       { currentTarget: HTMLElement, relatedTarget: HTMLElement }) => {
    if (!evt.currentTarget.contains(evt.relatedTarget)) {
      this.setState({
        open: false
      });
    }
  };
  render() {
      return (
        <div className="header__bottom" onBlur={this.handleClickOutside}>
   ...
```

Comment: Never used Flow, but in TypeScript I usually run into that if TS doesn't think `currentTarget` is a `HTMLElement` (e.g., it thinks it's a more generic `Element` which doesn't have `contains()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it would useful to someone:
the error is in `SyntheticEventType`.
So instead of line -

```
handleClickOutside = (evt: SyntheticMouseEvent<> & ...
```

should be

```
handleClickOutside = (evt: SyntheticFocusEvent<'blur'> &...
```

In that case for **eventTarget** `contains` method exists.